# UITableView center a UIImage and UILabel in viewForHeaderInSection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I wanna center vertically and horizontally an image inside of HeaderSection and a label inside of the image. But I don't have a clear idea about how make that. My code is:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_title_category"];
    UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)] autorelease];
    UILabel *sectionTitle = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 30)] autorelease];

    UIImageView *sectionHeaderBG;
    sectionTitle.text = @"Trial"; //[[tableDataSource objectAtIndex: section] objectForKey: @"Title"];
    sectionTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    sectionTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14];
    sectionTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    sectionTitle.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.4];
    sectionTitle.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
    sectionTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0];
    sectionHeaderBG = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _tableView.frame.size.width/2, image.size.height)];
    sectionHeaderBG.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_title_category"];
     [headerView addSubview:sectionHeaderBG];
                [headerView addSubview:sectionTitle];
                return headerView;
}
```

But this code not center anything... Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the size, in pixels, of the "bg_title_category" image?

Comment: I wonder how this code is even running... you have two variables called 'image' in your method. Having two variables with the same name in the same scope is an error

Comment: @rmaddy:The trick of this is that the size of the image will be change, because this will be for iPad & iPhone

Comment: @LuisCien: Sorry!! I change my code of position for can post it. If you look this variable never is called at the position of the second variable. Is my fault for repositioning the code. Anyway, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating `headerView` with origin (0,0) and it's size the same one as your image; then you're adding all of your views to `headerView`. When the table view adds this header view it will not be centered, rather it'll placed at (0,0).

What I'd suggest you to do is to create `headerView` with the same origin (0,0) but with the width of your `tableView` and the height depening on you. Let's just assume for now the height will be the same as your image plus 10px at the top and bottom just to give it some margin. Then you can add your `UIImageView` and `UILabel` inside `headerView` and center them with respect to it. It'd be something like this:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_title_category"];

    // Create your headerView with the same width as the tableView and a little taller than the image
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, tableView.bounds.size.width, image.size.height + 20)]; //10px top and 10px bottom. Just for illustration purposes.

    // Create the image view 
    UIImageView *sectionHeaderBG = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    // Now center it and add it to headerView
    sectionHeaderBG.center = CGPointMake(headerView.bounds.size.width/2, headerView.bounds.size.height/2);
    [headerView addSubview: [sectionHeaderBG autorelease]];

    // Now it's turn of the label. Again I suggest using the tableView's width
    UILabel *sectionTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)];

    // Now center it. You could even do this when creating it's frame
    sectionTitle.center = CGPointMake(headerView.bounds.size.width/2, headerView.bounds.size.height/2);
    // do the rest of the configuration for your label...
    // and add it to headerView
    [headerView addSubview: [sectionTitle autorelease]];

    return [headerView autorelease];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks!! It will help me a lot :)